# My store currency euro but on checkout page currency showing in dollar in magento2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

All prices are in euro but charged currency showing in dollar in Magento2
How to change Dollor to Euro for checkout page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this 
https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-currency-magento-2.html

You will find more details.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by setting euro as base currency from Magnto Admin

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Currency Setup

Comment: but i have multiple store i want currency store wise any other solution?

Comment: @JugalKishor try to change currency setup for each store

Answer (score 0):

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-checkout-with-display-currency-extension.html

You Must Use this module for fix this issue. I used in 5 websites, This working fine.